# How to make a generic filter that returns the array elements passed in generic <T>

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a `Parent` interface which is extended by `ChildA` and `ChildB`;

```
interface Parent {
  sharedProp: string,
}

interface ChildA extends Parent { 
  onlyInA: string,
}

interface ChildB extends Parent { 
  onlyInB: number
}
```

I have an array that contains the union array types:

```
const entities: (ChildA|ChildB)[] = [
  {
    sharedProp: "this will be B",
    onlyInA: "because Im a"
  }, {
    sharedProp: "this will be B",
    onlyInB: 12345
  }
]
```

I've made the non generic function that does what I want:

```
const childrenWithCertainSharedProp = (sharedProp: string): ChildA[] => {
    return entities
        .filter(isChildA)
        .filter(e => e.sharedProp === sharedProp);
}
```

I could do `console.log(childrenWithCertainSharedProp('xxx'));`

[Here is a demo.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=51#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACACo20poN7BpoDOAFttACYawD2ADgFymSwQDmANMAL4gQYCFOgDCZUABsqAQTTQAHjHBUSmSnnxoiaOuEkBPAJLgZLEm049%20YKHCSo04qVQBC8pblXqcm7cT1DE1cWcABXAFsAIzg%20EGQ9C3koUEhQaBIWAApnaRkAH1y3AEoAbQBdNABeNFKdQmJickoaemY0ACIFbo6eRt19Y1MWDpjkRDCSdCMItEQOnV4uAh0mihxWxhHuhV7VgaDwELQARgAmAGYAFgBWReBy%20MTINFASIrkarIYNSBYsXyQYosH6A15qD7VAB8K36OEgYVg4DQ31%20cwhEjyxQAdIEhnIAIRVGphFTQeAQagAbjiwAS4CSbyK7i%20oNwfx87OBaDZeDeTkxbmhsMa8MRyNRYMQGJcrhxeOCaCJJLJFPA1Np9KSyEFvgA6qkyKI4JBEBAAMrrai0RjVFHNDY29oWdjgDjcj4VYUNUXQBFI5JpNIZfb9bEUyRCLJMwUyYqhxrhqRR9BVGHQbEO61tarE0hWzYMYo0mxauiSDOSOgcLI6lz6w3G2Cmi0Fp1ZADkOw7xWLQA)

But as you can see I put the return as `ChildA[]` and I could do the same with `ChildB[]`.

I want something resembling the following which I could not make work:

```
const childrenWithCertainSharedProp = <T>(sharedProp: string): T[] => {
    return entities
        .filter(/* filter depending on T */)
        .filter(e => e.sharedProp === sharedProp);
}
```

Basically what I want is somehow to type guard generically, in a way that I make sure that if I pass `<ChildA>` I will make sure it will filter only `ChildA` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to at least pass an argument that has the type since at runtime typescript won't have any access to the type params.

As a warning, this will only be as good as your typeGuards.

```
const childrenWithCertainSharedProp = <T extends ChildA | ChildB>(arr: T[], sharedProp: string): T[] => {
  return arr.filter(e => e.sharedProp === sharedProp);
}

console.log(childrenWithCertainSharedProp(entities.filter(isChildA), 'xxx')[0].onlyInA);
console.log(childrenWithCertainSharedProp(entities.filter(isChildB), 'xxx')[0].onlyInB);
```